# How to prove that these groups are isomorphic (or not)?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, group-isomorphism

I have these following groups.

1. ($\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z},+) \times(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z},+) \times (\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z},+)$
2. ($\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}\backslash$ {0}$,\cdot)$ and ($\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}\backslash$ {0}$,\cdot)$

For the first question, I tried to reduce them using gcd(14,7)=2 and gcd(21,15) = 3, which give me ($\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z},+) \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},+) \times(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z},+) \times (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},+) $ and $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z},+)  \times (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},+)\times (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z},+) \times (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z},+)$ With the chinese remainder theorem, we can conclude that they are isomorphic.

For the second,

$(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}\backslash$ {0}$,\cdot) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\backslash$ {0}$,\cdot) \times (\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}\backslash$ {0}$,\cdot)$ with the chinese remainder theorem but I don't know what to do after that.

Can someone give me some hints please?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE, David. Your CRT assertion is correct for the additive groups, but false for the multiplicative groups. Consider the Euler totients of 21 and 13. Do they agree? What structure will the multiplicative group have? (eg. cyclic? dihedral? symmetric?)

Comment: Please note:  3 and 7 are both nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$ yet their product is $0$.  So $\mathbb{Z}_{21}-\{0\}$ isn't even closed under multiplication.  There must be a typo in your problem somewhere (or it is a poorly-constructed problem).

Comment: @Randall  sadly there's no typo

Comment: @bounceback thanks I'll come back later with another assertion

Comment: @bouceback let's try something. We've got $\varphi(13) = \varphi(21) = 12$. For sure, $(\mathbb{Z}$\13$\mathbb{Z}$\{0},$\cdot$) is cyclic but  $(\mathbb{Z}$\21$\mathbb{Z}$\{0},$\cdot$) too because 21 = 3 x 7 product of two odd prime numbers. So $(\mathbb{Z}$\3$\mathbb{Z})^\times) = {\pm 1,\pm2,}$ , $(\mathbb{Z}$\7$\mathbb{Z})^\times)$= etc. and we do the same for the other group. Whatever the number used a^12 $\equiv 1 \mod {n}$. So they are isomorphic

Comment: Yes, that would be true if it weren't for Randall's observation!